# Getting precision of integer given a float precision point

Tags: floating-point

Let's say I have the number `1234567` and I want to get the value `12.34567` with a precision point of `0.01`. How would I go about doing this?

If I multiply the precision point and the number, I end up with `12345.67` which is the opposite of what I need and I am unsure how to approach this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the logic behind the statement that "the value `12.34567` has a a precision point of `0.01`"???

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the number by $10^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}$ shifts the decimal point to just after the first digit, and then you can further shift the decimal point relative to that number.

---

$$
\log n - 1 < \lfloor\log n\rfloor \le \log n\\
10^{\log n-1} < 10^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor} \le 10^{\log n}\\
\frac n{10} < 10^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor} \le n\\
\frac{n}{n/10} > \frac n{10^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}} \ge \frac nn\\
10 > \frac n{10^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}} \ge 1\\
$$